# How to pass data in flutter on Stateless Widget?

Tags: flutter, navigation

I'm trying to do my school assignment, and have run into difficulty with passing data into Stateless Widgets. I have the following classes:

```
    class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Page1(),
    );
  }
}




class Page1 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
          child: ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.push(
              context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Page2(messageData: messageData)));
        },
        child: Text('Request Chat'),
      )),
    );
  }
}




class Page2 extends StatelessWidget {
  //Navigation
  static Route route(MessageData data) => MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => Page2(
          messageData: data,
        ),
      );

  const Page2({Key? key, required this.messageData}) : super(key: key);

  final MessageData messageData;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        iconTheme: Theme.of(context).iconTheme,
        centerTitle: false,
),
),
},


@immutable
class MessageData {
  const MessageData(
      {required this.senderName,
      required this.message,
      required this.messageDate,
      required this.dateMessage,
      required this.profilePicture});

  final String senderName;
  final String message;
  final DateTime messageDate;
  final String dateMessage;
  final String profilePicture;
}
```

There is my messageData above that I need to pass.

Basically, I want to be able to Navigate to Page2 but I keep getting an error at `Navigator.push()` .
Error details: `Type' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'MessageData'.`

And when there are no arguments on Page2() the error message: `The named parameter 'messageData' is required, but there's no corresponding argument.`

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass data using Constructor. I hope you will get an idea from this [link](http://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/navigation/passing-data).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can pass arguments to widgets just like you pass to `Flutter`'s widgets:

```dart
///Creating Page2 instances
Page2(text: 'text');
Page2.otherConstructor('text');

///This is how you pass values to widgets
class Page2 extends StatelessWidget {
  //Pass `this.field` to the constructor so that you are asking for the field you created.
  const Page2({Key? key, required this.text}) : super(key: key);
  const Page2.otherConstructor(this.text);

  final String text;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Text(text),
    );
  }
}
```

And in case it's a `StatefulWidget` in the `State` you can access the values with `widget.field`.

Comment: Hi Felipe , Thank you for your assistance. I'm still struggling to get through to the solution. I've also attached my messageData on the problem above. Your assistance will be higly appreciated

Comment: The thing is that you haven't created any `MessageData` object in your code, so if I try to run what you've given I won't get to your error. You need to initialize an object first.